# Why is this global variable not being changed?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why does this turn up null instead of being set to the data returned from the ajax call? It must be something simple i am overlooking.

```
var message;

$(document).ready(function(){
    fbFetchMessage();
    alert(message);
});

function fbFetchMessage(){
    var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/companyname/feed?callback=?";  
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            message = json.data[0].message;
        });
}
```

Comment: You have to wait until the AJAX call finished. Just put the alert in the callback function of `jetJSON` or have it inside timer.

Comment: putting the alert in a timer is a bug waiting to happen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

message **is** being changed, but **after** you call alert

try this code and see for youself:

```
var message;

$(document).ready(function(){
    fbFetchMessage();
    alert(message);
});

function fbFetchMessage(){
    var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/companyname/feed?callback=?";  
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            message = json.data[0].message;
            alert("really it gets changed:"+message);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`$.getJSON` like any other `.ajax()` (actually, AJAX in general) runs **asyncronously** (by default).

That means, you try to alert `message` **before** your success-handler can actually define it.

To solve that, you might want to use jQuerys [`Deferred`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) objects (if you're using 1.5.0+)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    fbFetchMessage().done(function(json) {
        alert(json.data[0].message); // data will also be the result which was returned
    });
});

function fbFetchMessage(){
    var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/companyname/feed?callback=?";  
    return $.getJSON(url);
}
```