# jquery problem with variable

Tags: jquery, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this global variable not being changed???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005432/why-is-this-global-variable-not-being-changed)

Hi, have this code to auth my app via ajax:

```
        var myAuth = false;
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'loading.php',
             data: { token: 123456789},
             success: function(data){
               if (data.response == 'OK'){
                    myAuth = true;
               }else{
                    myAuth = false;
               }
             }
           });     

if (myAuth == true){
do something
}
```

why myAuth don't get the value after response is OK?

Comment: It seems that in your code you are trying to catch the myAuth value right after the $.ajax call, which is assyncronous and at the that point probably will not be true already. You should call a function instead of setting the myAuth = true, after the server response.

Answer (score 2):

Because XHR is ran asynchronous (when used in the manner in your example).

You need to place that code in the `success` callback.

At the moment, the condition is evaluated as soon as the request is made, not when the request is finished. Therefore, `myAuth` is always set to its initial value of `false`.

The other way would be to make the request synchronous, but this locks the browser UI whilst the request is open and is considered bad practice for that reason.